# ColdFusion looping through a list with text qualifiers

Tags: list, loops, text, coldfusion, delimiter

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement text qualifiers (surrounding quotes) in cfloop lists. cfloop list doesn't seem to have an option for ignoring text between certain characters. Of course I could just change the delimiter but I'm surprised I can't figure out a more elegant way to do this and now it's got me curious...

Here is the list I'm looping through:

```
Mockup_"/docs/R0001/Mockup_2014-07-10.pdf"_MDEXTER_2014-07-10
```

And of course this is the loop:

```
<cfloop list="#list#" delimiters="_" index="i">
    #i#
</cfloop>
```

So it is treating

```
"/docs/R0001/Mockup
```

and

```
2014-07-10.pdf"
```

as separate elements whereas they need to form one URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't a list operation, for the reasons you have noticed: a list in CFML is simply a string in which character(s) are treated as delimiters. There is no concept of "escaped" delimiters as you are wanting. If the pattern of the record you want is always the same, you perhaps want to do some manner of regex matching instead. You don't really provide enough info of the problem domain to help you with that though. Perhaps describe the problem, rather than approach it from a not-working-solution perspective?

Comment: Seems like a standard CSV parsing problem, perhaps just looking for a existing CSV parser on cflib.org will give you a ready to use solution or a google search on "CSV parser CFML" may yield a ready to plugin solution.

If you are on railo this may help:

http://www.railodeveloper.com/post.cfm/railo-custom-tag-cfcsv

Answer (score 1):

If the line of text is going to be relatively constant why not do this?

```
strList1 = listGetat('Mockup_"/docs/R0001/Mockup_2014-07-10.pdf"_MDEXTER_2014-07-10',2,'"');

writeDump(strList1);
```

The above will produce this without quotes: "/docs/R0001/Mockup_2014-07-10.pdf"

Again this assumes a standard format.